# TSQL Table Transformation Fields => Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following table layout.  Each line value will always be unique.  There will never be more than one instance of the same Id, Name, and Line.

```
Id Name Line
1  A    Z
2  B    Y
3  C    X
3  C    W
4  D    W
```

I would like to query the data so that the Line field becomes a column.  If the value exists, a 1 is applied in the field data, otherwise a 0.  e.g.

```
Id Name Z Y X W
1  A    1 0 0 0
2  B    0 1 0 0
3  C    0 0 1 1
4  D    0 0 0 1
```

The field names W, X, Y, Z are just examples of field values, so I can't apply an operator to explicitly check, for example, 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'.  These could change at any time and are not restricted to a finate set of values.  The column names in the result-set should reflect the unique field values as columns.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, in the result they would be the names of the columns -- they could be called anything.

Comment: "If the value exists, a 1 is applied in the field data" - does that mean 1 indicates at least one instance of the value, or should that number reflect the count of that value associated to the group?

Comment: @OMG I updated the question.  Each row is unique.  There will never be more than one instance of an Id, Name, and Line.

Comment: Added the dynamic answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a standard pivot query.

If 1 represents a boolean indicator - use:

```
  SELECT t.id,
         t.name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.line = 'Z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Z,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.line = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Y,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.line = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS X,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.line = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS W
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

If 1 represents the number of records with that value for the group, use:

```
  SELECT t.id,
         t.name,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.line = 'Z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Z,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.line = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Y,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.line = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS X,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.line = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS W
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

Comment: @flato: To get the highest value for that column in the group--it's the MAX that allows the result set to "flatten" like you see in the expected output.  Because otherwise, you'd see a row per column comparison for each `id` and `name` pair.

Comment: +1 Slightly different approach to mine which confused me momentarily hence fleeting comment you may have seen!

Comment: This assumes that my line values will always be W, X, Y, or Z.  These are simply examples.  The values that are listed can be anything within the constraints of a column name. I could have a thousand t.line values which are unique.

Comment: @George: In order to accommodate that, you need to use dynamic SQL - I highly recommend reading [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for some perspective on dynamic SQL options on SQL Server.

Comment: @George - That's what I meant when I asked if they were fixed.

Comment: I added the dynamic pivot query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586909/tsql-table-transformation-fields-columns/3587187#3587187

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** following update in question

SQL Server does not support dynamic pivoting.

To do this you could either use dynamic SQL to generate a query along the following lines.

```
SELECT 
       Id ,Name, 
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Line='Z' THEN 1 END),0) AS Z,
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Line='Y' THEN 1 END),0) AS Y,
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Line='X' THEN 1 END),0) AS X,
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Line='W' THEN 1 END),0) AS W
FROM T
 GROUP BY Id ,Name
```

Or an alternative which I have read about but not actually tried is to leverage the Access `Transform` function by setting up an Access database with a linked table pointing at the SQL Server table then query the Access database from SQL Server!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the dynamic version

Test table

```
create table #test(id int,name char(1),line char(1))

insert #test values(1 , 'A','Z')
insert #test values(2 , 'B','Y')
insert #test values(3 , 'C','X')
insert #test values(4 , 'C','W')
insert #test values(5 , 'D','W')
insert #test values(5 , 'D','W')
insert #test values(5 , 'D','P')
```

Now run this

```
declare @names nvarchar(4000)

SELECT @names =''
  SELECT  @names    = @names +   line +', '  
    FROM (SELECT distinct  line from #test) x

SELECT @names = LEFT(@names,(LEN(@names) -1))

exec('
SELECT *
 FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name,Line
FROM #test
    ) AS pivTemp
PIVOT
(   COUNT(Line)
    FOR Line IN (' + @names +' )
) AS pivTable ')
```

Now add one row to the table and run the query above again and you will see the B

```
insert #test values(5 , 'D','B')
```

**Caution**: Of course all the problems with dynamic SQL apply, if you can use sp_executeSQL but since parameters are not use like that in the query there really is no point

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a finite number of values for Line that you could enumerate:

```
declare @MyTable table (
    Id int,
    Name char(1),
    Line char(1)
)

insert into @MyTable
    (Id, Name, Line)
    select 1,'A','Z'
    union all
    select 2,'B','Y'
    union all
    select 3,'C','X'
    union all
    select 3,'C','W'
    union all
    select 4,'D','W'

SELECT Id, Name, Z, Y, X, W
    FROM (SELECT Id, Name, Line
            FROM @MyTable) up
    PIVOT (count(Line) FOR Line IN (Z, Y, X, W)) AS pvt
    ORDER BY Id
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SQL Server, you could possibly use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) operator intended for this purpose.

Comment: Yes. [SQLMenace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586909/tsql-table-transformation-fields-columns/3587015#3587015) and [I](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586909/tsql-table-transformation-fields-columns/3586982#3586982) have both provided answers using PIVOT.

Comment: SQL Server *2005+* supports PIVOT; Oracle 11gR2 is the only other DB I'm aware of that supports `PIVOT`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this for a SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) report, or could possibly switch to using one, then stop now and go throw a Matrix control onto your report. Poof! You're done! Happy as a clam with your data pivoted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather exotic approach (using sample data from the old Northwind database). It's adapted from the version [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/browse_thread/thread/cf19f40636353a4c/c107658bfc92ef8a?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=pivot+access+transform+kass#c107658bfc92ef8a), which no longer worked due to the deprecation of DBCC RENAMECOLUMN and the addition of PIVOT as a keyword.

```
set nocount on 
create table Sales ( 
  AccountCode char(5), 
  Category varchar(10), 
  Amount decimal(8,2) 
) 
--Populate table with sample data 
insert into Sales 
select customerID, 'Emp'+CAST(EmployeeID as char), sum(Freight) 
from Northwind.dbo.orders 
group by customerID, EmployeeID 
create unique clustered index Sales_AC_C 
on Sales(AccountCode,Category) 
--Create table to hold data column names and positions 
select A.Category, 
       count(distinct B.Category) AS Position 
into #columns 
from Sales A join Sales B 
on A.Category >= B.Category 
group by A.Category 
create unique clustered index #columns_P on #columns(Position) 
create unique index #columns_C on #columns(Category) 
--Generate first column of Pivot table 
select distinct AccountCode into Pivoted from Sales 
--Find number of data columns to be added to Pivoted table 
declare @datacols int 
select @datacols = max(Position) from #columns 
--Add data columns one by one in the correct order 
declare @i int 
set @i = 0 
while @i < @datacols begin 
  set @i = @i + 1 
--Add next data column to Pivoted table 
  select P.*, isnull(( 
    select Amount 
    from Sales S join #columns C 
    on C.Position = @i 
    and C.Category = S.Category 
    where P.AccountCode = S.AccountCode),0) AS X 
  into PivotedAugmented 
  from Pivoted P 
--Name new data column correctly 
  declare @c sysname 
  select @c = Category 
  from #columns 
  where Position = @i 
  exec sp_rename '[dbo].[PivotedAugmented].[X]', @c, 'COLUMN'
--Replace Pivoted table with new table 
  drop table Pivoted 
  select * into Pivoted from PivotedAugmented 
  drop table PivotedAugmented 
end 
select * from Pivoted 
go 
drop table Pivoted 
drop table #columns 
drop table Sales
```