# Converting rows into columns tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have a table like

```
CId| RId|  No
---+----+----
  1|  10| 100    
  1|  20|  20    
  1|  30|  10    
  2|  10| 200    
  2|  30|  20    
  3|  40|  25
```

here, RId       represents "NoToAttend" (10),"NoNotToAttend" (20),"NoWait"(30),"Backup" (40) etc...

I need to have a result table that will look like

```
Cid|  "NoToAttend"|   "NoNotToAttend"| "NoWait"|  "Backup"
---+--------------+------------------+---------+----------
  1|           100|                20|     null|
  2|           200|              null|       20|     null
  3|          null|              null|     null|       25
```

I am not sure on how to use PIVOT. Need help on this

Comment: One more answer already available @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/3586937/1661861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) Function and just alias your columns:

```
SELECT  pvt.CID,
        [NoToAttend] = pvt.[10],
        [NoNotToAttend] = pvt.[20],
        [NoWait] = pvt.[30],
        [Backup] = pvt.[40]
FROM    T
        PIVOT
        (   SUM([No])
            FOR RID IN ([10], [20, [30], [40])
        ) pvt;
```